# how to locate a custome php function

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am a c# developer but I have a website for my family business that has been developed using PHP, woocommerce and wordpress about 5 years ago by a developer that I can't connect with him anymore. the problem is as following:- I did an update to the woocomerce plugin so I can use quick books when I did that the update the category page (which I know for a fact that he did custom build it ) lost the text under the images, I did inspect the elements in the browser, the text is their but there is a lot of space that why it is hidden , i don't know why this happened after the update but anyways, when I checked the page tab in the wordpress I did find this line of code

```
<pre class="brush: php; gutter: false">[product_categories per_page="12" columns="3" orderby="date" order="asc"]</pre>
```

As I said I don't know much of PHP but I expect "product_categories" is a function located in some file

also when I checked the inspect tab in the browser I found that the text and the image of the category is inheriting form class "product-category" "product" "first"

this is the line of the html of one of the categories just to have a better idea

```
<li class="product-category product first">  
<a href="https://www.WebsiteName.ca/product-category/backdrops/">
<img src="https://www.WebsiteName.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/backdrops-         300x300.jpg" alt="Backdrops" srcset="https://www.mosaiceventrentals.ca/wp-   content/uploads/2017/02/backdrops-300x300.jpg 300w, https://www.WebsiteName.ca   /wp-content/uploads/2017/02/backdrops-150x150.jpg 150w, https://www.WebsiteName.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/backdrops-180x180.jpg 180w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" width="300" height="300">        
    <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">
    Backdrops
     <mark class="count">(10)</mark>        
    </h2>
    </a></li>
```

-I did try to download all the files from the server and search in each file for this function but no luck

- I checked the bootstrap file for for the function "product-category" "product" "first" but I didn't find these classes

Basically I want to remove all extra space so the title can appear under the image but I want to know how to locate the file it is coded in

Comment: How did you _"download all the files"_? How did you try searching them? What you're looking for is a [Wordpress shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). There will be a line in a `.php` file somewhere with `add_shortcode('product_categories', 'some_function_name_or_reference')`

Comment: thanks for the reply, the way I downloaded them is going to public_html folder on the godddy server and download the all the php files  present, is their a better way to search in them?

Comment: Phil is correct you need to look for shortcodes. Updating can cause issues especially if the developer was a noob, do you know how your developer made changes? Did he create a separate plugin or did he edit the core files of wordpress / woocommerce?

Comment: It's not typical in Wordpress but files _can_ be placed outside the document-root (ie the `public_html` folder). It's unlikely though. Searching in the files depends on your operating system though most decent text-editors (VSCode, Sublime, Notepad++, etc) or IDEs (Webstorm, Netbeans, etc) can do a _"search in files"_. Some developers also include PHP code in files not necessarily with the `.php` extension, eg `.inc`. I would just search in **all** files

Comment: For example, on Mac / Linux, I would use `find . -type f -exec grep product_categories {} \; -print`. On Windows, you might be able to use the file search but I'd more readily use a text editor like VSCode

Comment: Oh, when downloading, make sure it's a recursive download, ie **all files and folders**.

Comment: @Second2None I don't think he created a new plugin I doubt that he wasn't that strong at the time
@ Phil I didn;t think to check outside the public_html let me check that, I am currently using vs Cod.

Comment: If he didn't make a plugin or child theme, due to the update (if you updated wordpress as well) those changes may be lost unfortunately.  I'd be running the search Phil recommended `add_shortcode('product_categories'` as that will give you the function name you can check. If that comes back empty I'd run `product_categories` as a last hope that maybe you missed a file containing the shortcode and can trace it back.

Comment: Though all the points mentioned in the above comment are valid, I would suggest that the very first place to check for is, the "functions.php" file of the active theme. If that developer has done the customization righty, then that function has to be in the functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

so after searching for a while I started to think out side of the box and discovered that the their was a line spacing error in the paragraph before the category list that was affecting the appearance of category titles. one other thing I found is that the new update for the woocommerce have a function to create a category list that link to the list of products under each category and the styling is much better than the custom made one.
just a reference to do that is as following:-
1- Dashboard --> Products --> Categories and you can add, edit and delete categories
2- in order to view the shop page as categories NOT the products you go to Dashboard --> Appearance --> customize --> woocommerce --> Product Catalog --> then select Show categories
3- then in order to add the welcome paragraph  just go to Dashboard-->Pages--> All Pages select the shop page and click edit and just write the welcome paragraph.

thanks everyone for your help and suppourt